# Is show() the correct way to return a String representation of a struct?

Tags: julia, tostring

In `C#` and `Java`, we have the `toString()` method to return a `String` representation of an object.

The closest I've seen in Julia is [`show()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.show-Tuple%7BIO,%20Any,%20Any%7D), but I'm not entirely sure if it's the correct function.

```
struct Person
   name::String
   age::Int32
end

amber = Person("Amber",22) 
println(amber) # Output: Person("Amber", 22)
```

If I want a little more control over the return `String`, I can do:

```
function Base.show(io::IO, person::Person)
    return "Name: $(person.name) Age: $(person.age)"
end

println(show(amber)) # Output: Name: Amber Age: 22
```

Do I have to call `show()` directly everytime? Can I pass it to `println()` and have it call `show()`? In `C#` and `Java`, if `toString()` is overridden, `Console.writeLine()` or `System.out.println()` will call `toString()`, no need to call it directly.

Comment: Note there is `show()` and `display()` and I am not sure what the difference is. You are correct though there should be a standard way to convert things into strings for other uses other than for display purposes.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41929009/13813219

Comment: @JAlex - It seems [`show()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.Multimedia.display) is the correct method to use when you want to output a `struct` as a `String`. Consider this quote from the documentation:  *In general, you cannot assume that display output goes to stdout (unlike print(x) or show(x)). For example, `display(x)` may open up a separate window with an image.*

Comment: This does not match the `toString()` behavior as you cannot write `s = show(p)` and expect a string stored in `s`. I think what you are looking for is `string()` and I have included it in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works the same in Julia:

```
julia> struct Person
          name::String
             age::Int32
       end

julia>

julia> amber = Person("Amber",22)
Person("Amber", 22)

julia> Base.show(io::IO, person::Person) = print(io, "Name: $(person.name) Age: $(person.age)")

julia> amber
Name: Amber Age: 22
```

This question is close to a duplicate of:

[How to overload Base.show for custom array types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962304/how-to-overload-base-show-for-custom-array-types)

Comment: I'm used to returning a `String` from `toString()`. I guess it's different in Julia. Using `println()` from `show()` seems like the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you define a `show(::IO, ::Person)` method:

```
julia> Base.show(io::IO, person::Person) = print(io, "The name is $(person.name), and they are $(person.age) years old")
```

You can use the `repr` function to get that output as a `String`:

```
julia> repr(amber)
"The name is Amber, and they are 22 years old"
```

You can also use the `string` function

```
julia> string(amber)
"The name is Amber, and they are 22 years old"
```

which by default falls back to `show` and so returns the same result. However, you can customize that by defining a `print(::IO, ::Person)` method:

```
julia> Base.print(io::IO, person::Person) = print(io, "name: $(person.name)\nage: $(person.age)")

julia> string(amber)
"name: Amber\nage: 22"

julia> repr(amber)
"The name is Amber, and they are 22 years old"
```

Note that this doesn't change the `repr` output: `repr` depends directly on `show`, whereas `string` depends on `print`.

In practice, you can use this to, for eg., have `string(amber)` return a plain list of information about the struct that could be useful for debugging, by defining `print` to print that information. And meanwhile, `repr(amber)` can return a human readable interpretation of the struct useful to the end user of the type, by defining `show` to show such an interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, if you want a `String`, we can always write our own `to_string()` function in addition to `show()`:

```
function toString(person::Person)
  return "Name $(person.name) Age: $(person.age)"
end

amber = Person("Amber",22) 
println(toString(amber)) # Output: Name Amber Age: 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you want to replicate `toString()` behavior if you can just define a `Base.string()` method

```
struct Person
   name::String
   age::Int32
end

Base.string(person::Person) = "Name: $(person.name) Age: $(person.age)"

p = Person("Julia", 5)

string(p)
"Name: Julia Age: 5"
```

Comment: Ah! I see what you did there. Now, it's almost like `C#` and `Java`. Can I call `println()` and have it return that `String`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. SInce every object in C# has a `.ToString()` what is called implicitly when you do `Console.WriteLine(obj)`, I was looking for a way to replicate this in Julia, by separating the steps of converting into a string, and then displaying the string. But it will include the quotes if it just shows up on the REPL.

Comment: The only way I know it's possible is to write your own `to_string()` function in addition to `show()`. When you want a `String`, just use `to_string()`, if you just want to print the details, use `show()` which `println()` will use anyways. It's also more clear, as `show()` give no indication that it returns anything.